# Kernel restarting every fitting model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

i tried to develop deep learning in my computer, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
My GPU : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090

NVCC:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0

Every time I import Tensorflow, I get this warning
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exGxj.png)

It state :

```
oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
```

```
successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
```

This message is also always displayed when compiling the model:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQJmK.png)

I assume the GPU is already connected, from the last line:

```
Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 16960 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.9
```

But every time I fit the model, it always restarting the kernel like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UgRD.png)

I have tried to change the TF version to a lower version, to change the environment, to change jupyter-lab from jupyter notebook. But all the efforts did not result in the expected run. I want to adapt my model.

I need your suggestion to solve this. I really need it!
Thank you so much for giving me an insight

I need to solve the restarting kernel each time the model is adjusted, I tried it with tensorflow.